SQL query that puts column headers into rows
I need help with a SQL query that basically takes columns/data that looks like this:
NDC | Address | Customer 
1   | 100     | Bobs
2   | 200     | USA Med
3   | 300     | Pharmville

and turns it into this:
NDC     | 1 | 2 | 3
Address | 100 | 200 | 300
Customer| Bobs | USA Med | Pharmville 

So basically, I need the NDC numbers to be the column headers. The headers used before will then become "rows". NDC will always be unique. I have tried some things with pivot/unpivot but cant figure it out.

Please edit your question and add in the query (or queries) you attempted and explain what result they're giving you vs what you expect.

Look into PIVOT.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

This is a standard unpivot + pivot, but you need to prepare your columns a bit:
SELECT  name, [1],[2],[3]
FROM
(
    SELECT name, val, NDC
    FROM (
        VALUES  (1, 100, N'Bobs')
        ,   (2, 200, N'USA Med')
        ,   (3, 300, N'Pharmville')
    ) t (NDC,Address,Customer)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Address', cast(address AS nvarchar(100))), ('Customer', Customer)) cv(name, val)
    ) x
 PIVOT(MAX(val) FOR NDC IN ([1],[2],[3])) pv

I prefer cross apply to UNPIVOT because you have INTs and NVARCHARs and they don't play well together.
The rest is standard pivot, not sure what tripped you up.

Was thinking the same +1, but I bet OP needs Columns to be dynamic.
